# Unpredictable behavior while saving images into storage

Tags: android, storage, runtime-permissions

[TLDR](https://www.howtogeek.com/435266/what-does-tldr-mean-and-how-do-you-use-it/#:%7E:text=TLDR%20(or%20TL%3BDR)%20is%20a%20common%20internet%20acronym,and%20TLDR%20is%20no%20exception.): ***Why isn't my app asking for runtime permissions despite I have written code for it?***

I am saving an image into the storage, on button click by doing something like this:

```
// Function triggered when save button is pressed
private void saveImage(){
    // Asking Runtime permissions for API level 23 and higher
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            finallySave();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},STORAGE_WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        // Do not ask permissions in the runtime for API level 22 and lower
        finallySave();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_WRITE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.size == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            finallySave()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

private void finallySave(){
    try {
        File outFile = new File(imagesDir, "Abc " + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        bitmaps[0].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        scanFile(outFile, "image/png");

    } catch (Exception unused) {

    }
}
```

The problem is, sometimes the image is not saved and the following error is shown:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Abc/Abc 1601370822977.png (Permission denied)`

I found out that this error is thrown when the application is not asking "storage write" permissions on the runtime. Which is the very origin of the problem that I am facing. My app is not asking for runtime permissions in some cases despite I have written the code for it. Replicating this bug is also very difficult because many times the saving operation is carried out successfully.

I am sure that my code for saving images works fine because sometimes it works (this happens when my app asks for runtime permissions) and sometimes it doesn't.

P.S: I encountered this problem when I had reinstalled my app (after uninstalling).

**EDIT**: imagesDir is a global variable I am assigning is as follows:

```
imagesDir = getImageDir(); // in onCreate

private File getImageDir() {
    File directory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Abc");
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not create directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    }
    scanFile(directory, "*/*");
    return directory;
}
```

Comment: `new File(imagesDir, "Abc " ` Include the code where you declare and assign imagesDir. Further 'Abc' is not in your error message.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I did that to obscure the directory name due to privacy reasons...

Comment: I believe that your query is out of the scope of this question as I have said that this issue occurs unpredictably. When this issue is not occurring the same code executes successfully. (The image gets saved successfully.) However, I have edited my question.

Comment: It only happens on devices with Androd 10?

Comment: No, I am testing on android oreo

Comment: `File outFile = new File(imagesDir, "Abc " + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");` It is no good to use a 'global' variable if you have a nice function. So better: `File outFile = new File(getImagesDir(), "Abc " + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");`

Comment: `My app is not asking for runtime permissions in some cases despite I have written the code for it. ` Unclear. It has to ask only one time and when granted never again. The user should look in the settings of the app to see if storage permission is on and if not toggle it.

Comment: Well, it turns out that when I press the save button the very first time after reinstalling the app. It doesn't even ask for permission (that should happen when permission is granted but actually it has not been granted) and throws that nasty error.

Comment: `It has to ask only one time and when granted never again.` Yes that totally makes sense but since I found out this weird behavior I thought I should share my problem with the community.